# Odd behavior in my code for a certain test case

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop

The program is supposed to swap neighbouring elements which don't have a common denominator, and an element can only be swapped once.
When i run the program, pretty much for any input works fine. Except for this one:

100 //input for number of elements

48 92 76 93 17 38 59 34 53 99 58 20 50 0 38 37 16 36 91 12 59 1 76 82 20 76 7 72 13 70 64 23 81 70 41 69 11 0 16 41 37 83 41 99 73 79 4 38 24 32 87 38 95 24 77 30 61 13 89 67 87 76 22 31 67 31 25 90 6 76 21 43 40 55 72 91 91 28 18 58 72 71 83 22 99 23 86 58 75 53 69 29 5 55 46 8 98 55 19 46 //the elements

For this input, the program hangs and prints nothing.  Does someone know what is going on in this particular case?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int nzd(int a, int b)
{
    if(a==b || b==0) 
        return a;
    if(a>b) 
        return nzd(a-b, b);
    return nzd(a, b-a);
}
int swap(int *niza, int i)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*(niza+i);
    *(niza+i)=*(niza+i+1);
    *(niza+i+1)=temp;
}
int main()
{
    int a[100], n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(i+1==n) continue;
        if(nzd(a[i], a[i+1])==1)
        {
            swap(a, i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you reveal why this test case fails?

Comment: That's my question.. I don't know.

Comment: He means how do you know it fails?  What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: It doesn't output. Nothing. I tried to print out something random before `scanf` in `main` and it doesn't even print that.

Comment: Are you actually typing 100 integers?

Comment: The first time i ran into his problem was during an exercise on my faculty's test software. You submit your code and it has test cases which it must output the same as the examples. You can do the same just enter 100 manually and copy and paste the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gcd function checks for the case of `b==0` but not the case for `a==0`.  Because you skip that check, you end up calling `nzd(0, b-0);` which is exactly the same as the prior call.  This puts you in an infinite recursion loop which will eventually cause a stack overflow.

Add the check for this case in your function:

```
if(a==b || b==0 || a == 0)
```

Also, a faster implementation of gcd, called Euclid's algorithm, is as follows:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (b==0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return (b, a%b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `nzd()` fails to handle the case `a == 0` correctly and gets stuck in an endless loop. You need to handle this case, too:

```
int nzd(int a, int b)
{
    if(a==b || a==0 || b==0) 
        return a;
    if(a>b) 
        return nzd(a-b, b);
    return nzd(a, b-a);
}
```